# How can I setup a Calendar that has a form field to submit appointments?

Tags: calendar, sapui5

I'm trying to implement the [planningCalendar](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.PlanningCalendar/samples) to have a form that allows a user to enter an appointment time. Once the appointment has been submitted, it should automatically be displayed on the Calendar. Not sure how to implement this.

Here's a [link](https://ide.c9.io/kunalojha1/sharepoint_calendar) to the Calendar I have already constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to update the model bound to the PlanningCalendar. The changes will automatically be reflected in the PlanningCalendar. You have to use the [JSONModel.setProperty()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#setProperty) to apply the changes to the model so that the model gets aware that there are changes. It will then update the bindings and with that the PlanningCalendar.

The following code should work with the [SAP example code](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendar/code/Page.controller.js) you have linked.

```
var model = this.getView().getModel();
//You will have to find the index of the person first. in this example: 0
var appointments = model.getProperty("/people/0/appointments");
appointments.push({
   start: myFormularsStartDate,
   end: myFormularsEndDate,
   title: myFormularsTitle,
   ...
});
model.setProperty("/peaople/0/appointments",appointments);
```

For more information on databinding in sapui5 i would recommend you take the [walkthrough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html).

Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PVfp3pXWpBmqxPZCwiZK?p=preview) here.

Comment: thanks for your input, can you provide an example of this working please?

Comment: I have created an example on Plunker. You can find the link at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i don't really understand the question here. If you view the [code](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendar/code) of your example, it gives a pretty clear understandig of how to work with this control. You can use the [DateTime Picker](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.DateTimePicker/preview) to a date and time, probably along with some other fields in a form to complete the header.

Comment: I'm trying to learn UI5 so I apologize if its not entirely clear- the examples are written in xml so its challenging in terms of readability. Outside of the examples in the explored section, it's hard for me to see how each component can work together. Specifically with the DateTime Picker, how can someone "submit"  the date onto the Calendar?

Comment: I'm afraid it's no simple answer. You should investigate somewhat more in UI5 in general. I can recommend the following site to learn UI5: [SDK](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218.html), [openSAP](https://open.sap.com/courses/fiori1) and first 3 weeks of [openSAP](https://open.sap.com/courses/mobile2). That would give you enough to start with UI5. Being successful in "learning" is by doing. Good luck! And let us know if the links are helpful.